# Propagate thread context when using vertx EventBus

Tags: quarkus, vertx-eventbus

I'm trying to get context propagation working when using event bus. I've created a simple flow following this guide https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-event-bus.

The code looks something like this:

```
@Inject
EventBus bus;

@Inject
@ManagedExecutorConfig(propagated = "SLF4J_MDC")
ManagedExecutor managedExecutor;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("{name}")
public Uni<String> hello(String name) {
    MDC.put("key", "someValue");
    Context context = Vertx.currentContext();
    ContextLocals.put("key", "Local Context");

    return bus.<String>request("greeting", name)
            .emitOn(managedExecutor)      // I also tried with - context::runOnContext
            .runSubscriptionOn(managedExecutor)
            .onItem().transform(Message::body);
}

@ConsumeEvent(value = "greeting")
@CurrentThreadContext(propagated = {"SLF4J_MDC"})
public String greeting(String name) {
    log.info("MDC2 ->>> {}", MDC.get("key"));                            // null
    log.info("from Context Local {}", ContextLocals.<String>get("key")); // null

    return "Hello " + name.toUpperCase();
}
```

SLF4J_MDC is a simple ThreadContextProvider implementation that I have registered in order to propagate the MDC values. I already tested this mechanism with regular async code and it worked, but not with eventBus.

Endpoint works as expected, but the values I am trying to log are null.

What is the right way to use context propagation in this scenario? Is it possible or is it not intended to be used in conjunction with event bus requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer - https://reactiverse.io/reactiverse-contextual-logging/

Contextual data is not propagated over the EventBus. In this case, it must be:

1. added to message headers on the sender side
2. retrieved from headers and saved again on the receiver side

This process can be automated with EventBus interceptors:

```
vertx.eventBus().addOutboundInterceptor(event -> {
  String requestId = ContextualData.get("requestId");
  if (requestId != null) {
    event.message().headers().add("requestId", requestId);
  }
  event.next();
});

vertx.eventBus().addInboundInterceptor(event -> {
  String requestId = event.message().headers().get("requestId");
  if (requestId != null) {
    ContextualData.put("requestId", requestId);
  }
  event.next();
});
```